# EMR - Use custom logging appender in Hadoop (and YARN)

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, configuration, emr

In our EMR clusters, we are using custom log4j-appenders and log4j.properties to allow us to forward logs to Splunk and to let us do some magic that the provided libraries and configurations don't know how to do.

In EMR 3.x we did it using a bootstrap action did:

1. Download from s3 our custom log4j appender jar, log4j.properties,
   container-log4j.properties that we customized.
2. Put our custom log4j appender jar into the yarn lib directory at
   /home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/.
3. Update Hadoop classpath to use our custom log4j appender
4. Push our modified container-log4j.properties into
   hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar at
   /home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/

All this worked and allowed us to use our appender all over the Hadoop processes.

We tried to upgrade to EMR release v4, but we noticed there is a major change in that bootstrap actions are being executed when there is no hadoop-yarn installed (the path /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/ doesn't exist), therefore there is no hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar to modify as it's not yet installed
(we modify the jar using the command: jar uf /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar  container-log4j.properties ) and not lib folder in which we can place our custom log4j-appender.

How can we make these changes in EMR 4.x, to allow our custom logging?

Answer (score 0):

You can override your log4j and container-log4j settings by following the instruction of this page.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com//ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-4.7.2/emr-configure-apps.html

and if you're using the UI, please fill the configuration, if you are using the CLI, please use --configurations file://./configurations.json

Comment: for the container-log4j, you may need bootstrap-actions to put it into /etc/hadoop/conf/, I don't see container-log4j is supported yet.